# Django template for loop - dependant on variable. 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, loops, templates

I'd like to run a for loop within a Django template, where the range is dependant on the value of a variable.

For the size of the name, add a space. The name is a string value.

```
{% for i in person.name|length %}                          
    &nbsp;
 {% endfor %}
```

Running this code produces an  'int' object is not iterable Django Error.

However, calling the following works, and will dispay the length of the name

```
{{ person.name|length }}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It might be better to use HTML/CSS for that sort of formatting, rather than adding a bunch of non-breaking spaces. E.g. Using right text-align: w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp

Comment: unfortunately text-align is not supported in <option>. that's what brought me to try this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python you cannot loop over an integer. This doesn't work:

```
for i in 4:
    # error
```

This is what you are currently doing with the for loop in your template. You can loop over each character in a string:

```
for c in person.name:
    # no error
```

You can do this in your template as follows:

```
{% for c in person.name %}                          
    &nbsp;
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. My aim was to add a space (for padding) for names under 30 characters. Something like {% for i in (30 - person.name) %}... I will see if i can do this.